# running stock python and Anaconda on the same windows machine

Tags: python, anaconda

I was looking for old questions related to this issue but was unable to find one.
If this question has been asked before, i apologize

I used to just use Anaconda for the purpose of coding in Python but then I found myself in need of a package which wasn't installable either via pip or conda. So, I had to install both stock python and Anaconda on my Windows laptop.

When i want to call upon stock python, i can just type `python` in a terminal window.

When I want to call upon Anaconda python, i first do `cd C:\Users\physics\Anaconda2` and then type `python` into a terminal window.

My question is, if one runs both stock python and Anaconda python on the same machine the way i described above, can there bill unintended consequences ?

(under environmental variables, i placed python above Anaconda so when i type python into a terminal window, the stock python gets called upon)

Answer (score 0):

No they are completely independent. To quote form the [docs](http://conda.readthedocs.org/en/latest/):

> The real power of conda comes from its ability to manage environments.
>   In conda, an environment can be thought of as a completely separate
>   installation.

Comment: also, is it true that if a python module cannot be installed via pip or conda, it is unlinkable to Anaconda?  For example, if i want to use `http://www.physics.rutgers.edu/pythtb/install.html`, i wont be able to do so in Anaconda?

Comment: You can install it in Anaconda through the Anaconda command prompt with `python setup.py install`